# Напомните, пожалуйста: как пишутся в паре актёр и роль?

Tags: пунктуация

> Алёна Хмельницкая заехала декорацией, которую она вздымала в рапиде
>   под торжественную музыку, Ленину-Калягину по голове, и он внятно,
>   легко и очень громко матернулся.

Дефис или всё ж таки тире?

Comment: В тексте тире не бывает без пробелов, а это ж получается какая пауза.

Comment: Тире без отбивок: *Ленину–Калягину*. В каких-то же случаях (кроме дат) употребляется. Я подзабыла в каких.

Comment: Интервал, перегон. В вашем случае уместны скобки.

Answer (score 1):

Тире. 
"Между двумя разными фамилиями необходимо тире, через дефис пишется двойная фамилия. Ср.: Глинка – Балакирев, но Римский-Корсаков." (из грамоты)

Comment: А в какой связи эта пара (Глинка – Балакирев) состоит?

Comment: @shampar, две разные фамилии: что там, что там.

Comment: В 1-м случае фамилии разных композиторов, во 2-м —  двойная у одного автора. «Глинка – Балакирев» у вас это соавторы?

Comment: Нет, это двойная фамилия.